# Calculate working hours using DATEDIFF in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I'm currently having a hard time calculating the total work hours of the employee, especially on the night shift people. Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @StartTime time
DECLARE @EndTime time

SELECT @StartTime = CAST('Jun 04 2018 8:00PM' as time)
SELECT @EndTime = CAST('Jun 04 2018 5:00AM' as time)

SELECT
SUM((DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartTime, @EndTime) - isnull(datediff(minute, break_start, break_end), 0))/ 60.0) 
FROM pmis.dbo.employee as a
LEFT JOIN pmis.dbo.time_reference as b ON b.code = ISNULL(a.TimeReference, 'TIME14')
    cross apply
    (
        select  break_start = case  when b.break_from between @StartTime and @EndTime
                 then b.break_from
                 when @StartTime between b.break_from and b.break_to
                 then @StartTime
                 else NULL
                end,
                break_end  = case   when b.break_to between @StartTime and @EndTime
                 then b.break_to
                 when @EndTime between b.break_from and b.break_to
                 then @EndTime
                end
        ) as d
WHERE
a.Shift = 0 and a.eid = 7078
```

What I get is when the given time is like this

```
@StartTime = 8:00 AM
@EndTime = 5:00 PM
```

THEN the result is `8.00` hrs exactly as I wanted but if it is like this

```
@StartTime = 8:00 PM
@EndTime = 5:00 AM
```

THEN I get `-15.00` How to solve this? Thanks

Comment: The way you deal with this is to store the date _and_ time together, as a timestamp of some sort.  Obviously, you will have problems with the graveyard shift since it wraps over to the next day.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that. I already fix it

Comment: -15 hours is actually correct. It is your data that is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

Try adding 1 day (1440 minutes) to the calculation when endtime when it is earlier than starttime. This will not handle breaks in graveyard shifts though. But your previous code had the same issue

```
SELECT
SUM((DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartTime, @EndTime)+ 
  CASE WHEN @StartTime > @EndTime THEN 1440 ELSE 0 END -- CHANGE IN CODE IS HERE
  - isnull(datediff(minute, break_start, break_end), 0))/ 60.0) 
FROM pmis.dbo.employee as a
LEFT JOIN pmis.dbo.time_reference as b 
ON b.code = ISNULL(a.TimeReference, 'TIME14')
    cross apply
    (
        select  break_start = case  when b.break_from between @StartTime and @EndTime
                 then b.break_from
                 when @StartTime between b.break_from and b.break_to
                 then @StartTime
                 else NULL
                end,
                break_end  = case   when b.break_to between @StartTime and @EndTime
                 then b.break_to
                 when @EndTime between b.break_from and b.break_to
                 then @EndTime
                end
        ) as d
WHERE
a.Shift = 0 and a.eid = 7078
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve it would be to use datetime data type instead of time, then you need to change these lines

```
DECLARE @StartTime datetime
DECLARE @EndTime datetime

SELECT @StartTime = CAST('Jun 04 2018 8:00PM' as datetime)
SELECT @EndTime = CAST('Jun 04 2018 5:00AM' as datetime)
```

Comment: You need to a condition to add 1 day to endtime for this to work - or better have the correct enddate, I agree it should not be converted to time